# Unable to call a function from an other class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating an app on Android studio using java and a SQLite database. 
I have created a function to get data from the database in a list but i am not able to call it from an other class.

```
public List getNumTicket(){
    List NumTicket=new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT nbTicket FROM TicketCaisse";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        NumTicket.add(cursor.getInt(0));
    }
    db.close();
    return NumTicket;
}
```

This function is in a class which is using SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class BaseSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public BaseSQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
{
    super(context,name,factory,version);
}
```

And i'm trying to call it from the class "accueil"

```
public class Accueil extends AppCompatActivity {
```

I would be very happy if you could help me on this one . If you need more infos ask me ;)

Comment: Which is the error message you are getting and at which stage are you getting an error message: at compile time or during runtime?

Comment: show how exactly you are trying to call it, and what is the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function belongs to the BaseSQLite class thus you need to instiantiate (create) a BaseSQlite object which uses the class constructor.

The class constructor is the following :-

```
public BaseSQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
{
    super(context,name,factory,version);
}
```

So you need to have code such as

```
    BaseSQLite name_of the_object = new BaseSQLite(
        context_to_be_used,
        Database_name,
        cursor_factory, // null will very likely suit
        version
    );
```

Once you have the object (`name_of_the object` if the above were used) you can then use it's methods (functions) so `name_of_object.getNumTicket()` will invoke the method(function).

More specifically :-

---

In `Accueil`'s `onCreate` method after the `setContentView` line have :-

> ```
>     BaseSQLite mybasesqlite = new BaseSQLite(this,"your_database_name",null,1);
>     List mylist = mybasesqlite.getNumTicket();
> ```

---

### Notes

- typically you'd have the database name null and version hard coded in the constrcutor, so you'd then only need to use `BaseSQLite mybasesqlite = new BaseSQLite(this);`
- e.g. The If the database were **mydatabase.d**b and the version were **1** then you could have :-

  `public BaseSQLite(Context context) {
      super(context,"mydatabase.db",null,1);
  }`
- null for the cursor factory is very likely fine at this stage.

---

However, I'd suggest having a single occurrence (constant), of the database name, version table names and columns and always refer to that  e.g.

```
public class BaseSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydatabase.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_TICKETCAISSE = "TicketCaisse";
    public static final String COL_TICKETCAISSE_NBTICKET = "nbTicket"

    public BaseSQLite(Context context) {
        super(context,DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
    }
    ......
    public List getNumTicket(){
        List NumTicket=new ArrayList();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL_TICKETCAISSE_NBTICKET + " FROM " + TB_TICKETCAISSE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            NumTicket.add(cursor.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TICKETCAISSE_NBTICKET)));
        }
        cursor.close() //<<<< ADDED should always close Cursors when done with them
        db.close();
        return NumTicket;
}
```

The corresponding Activity could be along the lines of :-

```
public class Accueil extends AppCompatActivity {

    BaseSQLite  mybasesqlite;      

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mybasesqlite = new BaseSQLite(this);
        List mylist = mybasesqlite.getNumTicket();

    }
    // if used in another method then
    private void doSomethingElse() {
        List myotherlist = mybasesqlite.getNumTicket();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Accueil extends AppCompatActivity {
oncreate{
BaseSQLite bsqlite = new BaseSQLite(//pass constructors what you are need);
bsqlite.getNumTicket();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `BaseSQLite.class` object

```
public List getNumTicket(){
    List NumTicket=new ArrayList();
    BaseSQLite db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT nbTicket FROM TicketCaisse";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
      {
      NumTicket.add(cursor.getInt(0));
      }
    db.close();
    return NumTicket;
}
```